# Android how to send GET and JSON data to server and get response

Tags: android, json, get

Hi i need to send a get to a server. and get  a response from the server.
the data is JSON. do i need to add the data to the URL like in the WEB ?
I have all the time errors need help

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String url = "http://api.avakoo.com/Entry.svc/JSON/Register?args=%7B%22password%22%3A%22vhfju%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22fhcnh%22%7D";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            String responseStr = out.toString();
```

I say some example but nationg work can someone advise to me how to send the date and get a response from the server.
when i but the URL in the browser i get a response.
i encode the data white the utf 8

Comment: Do some google. Lots of tutorials are available out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for your requirement

Downlooad Gson jar file

```
  String url = "Your url";

  grabURL(url);

        private void grabURL(String url) {


            new GrabURL().execute(url);


        }

  private void displayData(String response){


            String resp = response;

                JSONObject responseObj = null;

                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    responseObj = new JSONObject(response); 
                    JSONArray passDataListObj = responseObj.getJSONArray("your array list name from server");

                    ArrayList<ObjectTypeSpecifiedInServer>list = new ArrayList<ObjectTypeSpecifiedInServer>(); 
                    String[] passData_array = new String[passDataListObj.length()]; 

                    for (int i=0; i<passDataListObj.length(); i++){

                        //add to values to array
                        passData_array[i] = passDataListObj.getJSONObject(i).getString("KeyNameGivenForTheValue");

                        //get the value information JSON object
                        String passInfo = passDataListObj.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                        //create java object from the JSON object
                        ObjectType objectReference = gson.fromJson(objectReference , ObjectType.class);
                        }

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }



       class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
                private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
                private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
                HttpResponse response;
                private String content =  null;
                private boolean error = false;
                private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

                protected void onPreExecute() {

                    dialog.setMessage("Getting your data... Please wait...");
                    dialog.show();

                }

                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


                    String URL = null;

                    try {
                        URL = urls[0];
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
                         HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                         ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username.getText().toString()));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));

                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

                        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){

                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);

                            out.close();

                            content = out.toString();

                        } else{
                            //Closes the connection.

                            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        Log.w("HTTP2:",e );
                        content = e.getMessage();
                        error = true;
                        cancel(true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w("HTTP3:",e );
                        content = e.getMessage();
                        error = true;
                        cancel(true);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w("HTTP4:",e );
                        content = e.getMessage();
                        error = true;
                        cancel(true);
                    }

                    return content;
                }

                protected void onCancelled() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "Error connecting to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
                    toast.show();

                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast toast;
                    if (error) {
                        toast = Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        displayData(content);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps you.....

Comment: you mean to say response from the server for what request you had sent

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  String url = "http://api.avakoo.com/Entry.svc/JSON/Register";
  List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("column name", password));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("column name", email));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("column name",fhcnh ));
  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
  url += "?" + paramString;
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
  static InputStream is  = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Hope it will help..

Comment: make sure that the url that you specified is correct

Comment: this can be solved by using AsyncTask class and you should place the http code into the doInBackground() function